# Increasing the speed of logical iterations Python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, optimization, logic

I am building a ranking algorithm in Python to rank college basketball teams. The algorithm works as follows:

1. I have a data frame (5464 rows) with every college basketball game (we will call this `data_for_model`)
2. I have another data frame (353 rows) with every team and their current ranking (we will call this `model_df`)
3. The program I wrote iterates through each row of `data_for_model` (i.e., each game) and at each iteration it identifies the losing team and the winning team in `data_for_model`, then finds the rankings for both teams in `model_df`. If the winning team has a larger ranking (i.e., worse ranking) relative to the losing team, the winning team's ranking now takes on the value of the team in which they just defeated (i.e., the winning teams' rank improves). Additionally, the team they just defeated and all teams ranked below them (i.e., a larger, worse ranking) get 1 added to their ranking (i.e., their ranking becomes worse).

Currently, I have gotten the code to run all the way through in as little as 2 minutes. I would like to see if I can speed-up this loop because, ideally, I want to run it thousands of times with the initial rankings being random numbers (1-353) and get the average ranking over the thousands of final rankings. I am new to monitoring processes and optimizing code, so help would be much appreciated.

Here is some made-up data for a workable example:

```
# import dependencies
import pandas as pd

# create winning team list
Winning_Team = ['buffalo','st-johns-ny','seton-hall','providence','indiana']
# create losing team list
Losing_Team = ['saint-francis-pa','loyola-md','wagner','siena','chicago-state']
# put winning team and losing team into columns in data_for_model
data_for_model = pd.DataFrame({'Winning_Team': Winning_Team,
                              'Losing_Team': Losing_Team})

# create team list
Team = ['buffalo','st-johns-ny','seton-hall','providence','indiana',
        'saint-francis-pa','loyola-md','wagner','siena','chicago-state']
# create rank list (i.e., 1-10)
Rank = [10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1]
# put Team and Rank into columns in model_df
model_df = pd.DataFrame({'Team': Team,
                         'Rank': Rank})
```

Here is the code for the sorting algorithm:

```
for i in range(data_for_model.shape[0]):
    # set up logic for model
    winning_team = data_for_model['Winning_Team'].loc[i] 
    losing_team = data_for_model['Losing_Team'].loc[i]

    # get index and rank for winning team in model_df
    winning_team_index = model_df.loc[model_df['Team'] == winning_team, 'Random_Rank_{}'.format(models)].index[0]
    winning_team_rank = model_df['Random_Rank_{}'.format(models)].loc[winning_team_index]

    # get index and rank for losing team in model_df
    losing_team_index = model_df.loc[model_df['Team'] == losing_team, 'Random_Rank_{}'.format(models)].index[0]
    losing_team_rank = model_df['Random_Rank_{}'.format(models)].loc[losing_team_index]

    # if the winning team has a worse ranking
    if winning_team_rank > losing_team_rank:
        # increase the ranking by 1 for all random_rank >= losing_team_rank
        model_df['Random_Rank_{}'.format(models)] = model_df.apply(lambda x: x['Random_Rank_{}'.format(models)]+1 if x['Random_Rank_{}'.format(models)] >= losing_team_rank else x['Random_Rank_{}'.format(models)], axis=1)
        # then make the winning_team_rank equal the rank of the losing team
        model_df['Random_Rank_{}'.format(models)].loc[winning_team_index] = losing_team_rank
```